# Examine if app has been updated or installed newly

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

How do I check whether my app gets installed for the first time or updated? 
I want to introduce In-App-Purchasing,  my app will be free, while it was chargeable before. So if an user downloads my application for the first time he or she shall pay for some extra content, while users who bought the app before shall use these contents furthermore. 
Thanks for your help and excuse my quite bad english!

Comment: As of iOS 7, this can be done using receipt validation. The receipt includes information about the original *purchase version*.

Answer (score 0):

As of iOS 7, there is a supported way to detect this. There is a receipt from the app store which you can read and determine the original purchase date & version. Take a look at Apple's [Receipt validation guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/Chapters/ValidateLocally.html).

Comment: Thank you, but I don't see through that... How do I read out that receipt in Xcode? In the App Delegate?

Comment: You read it wherever you want to know when the app was installed. The app delegate would work.